# pssh multiple server execute command as root

Tags: linux, aix

I try to use pssh to execute command on multiplate server. And I have error

```
[5] 14:38:01 [FAILURE] xcasw2828102sj Exited with error code 126
sh: /bin/chpasswd: 0403-006 Execute permission denied.
```

Execute command:

```
pssh -A -l AXAIPL0201123 -x "-tt" -t600 -p5 -h servers.dat -i "sudo -S PASSWORD su -c"echo 'echo "username:password" | /bin/chpasswd -c'
```

when i login into server as this same password used in command i can login into root as well and execute "echo "username:password" | /bin/chpasswd -c" on aix

Comment: The syntax of your command seems wrong. sudo -S expects that the password comes from stdin, so you would need to pass the password via e.g. a pipe to sudo, like `echo PASSWORD|sudo -S` but I'd suggest changing this to password-less on the target servers. Furthermore, as sudo seems to be in use, why use it to run a full root shell just to issue a command? Also, I'm not sure how pssh or your local shell interacts with the multiple single and double quotes within your command line enclosed that follows after `-i` but I think you would need to escape the inner double quotes.

Comment: If sudo would be password-less then this should do it: `pssh -A -l AXAIPL0201123 -x "-tt" -t600 -p5 -h servers.dat -i "echo 'username:password' | sudo /bin/chpasswd -c"`